# why is [ for i in ${ARR[@]}; do echo ${i} ] printing space-delimited output?

Tags: bash

I have read input from file using:

```
declare -a ARR      
    readarray -t ARR < <(cat /etc/passwd | tr "\n" "\n" )
```

This prints it fine, but I want to access each line:

```
 printf '%s\n' "${ARR[@]}
```

This is splitting the input on spaces:

```
for i in ${ARR[@]}; do
        echo ${i}
    done
```

Does `echo` requires a particular option to print it correctly?
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127954/echo-changes-my-tabs-to-spaces), changing it to `echo "${i}"` should fix it, but it doesn't.
This has the same problem:

```
printf "${i} \n"
```

Comment: What is `tr "\n" "\n"` supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid splitting on spaces, replace:

```
for i in ${ARR[@]}; do
```

With:

```
for i in "${ARR[@]}"; do
```

Without the double-quotes, the shell does word-splitting.

It would also be best to replace `echo ${i}` with `echo "${i}"`.  Without the double-quotes the `${i}` will be subject to word-splitting (which will cause multiple spaces to be collapsed to one blank) and *pathname expansion* (which may cause words with shell-active characters to be replaced with filenames from the current directory).

Comment: Most variable/array/command expansions should be in double-quotes. There are some situations where it's safe to leave the double-quotes off, but IMO it's more bother to keep track of where it's safe, than it is to just always use double-quotes.

Comment: Note that, inside double quotes, `"${ARR[*]}"` uses the first character of `$IFS` for its separator.